# Completely reload a gamepage in monogame

Tags: xna, reload, monogame

I am trying to completely reload a gamepage in monogame - simply by touching a sprite on the page. I cannot find any solution for this.

In Android, I can call finish for the gameactivity, and then recreate a new one. How can I do that in monogame?

I am using WP8.0 SDK, monogame with XNA 4 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Android development, or specifically what you mean by "gamepage", but typically this type of thing is handled with "states" in game development. You can have a playing state, paused state, Main Menu state, etc, and you just pass the game object to each state class and have it override the update/draw methods with its own information.

So, in your case, you would be in the playing state of the game, and if the sprite is touched, you might want to go back to the main title, you can pass the game object to the Title Screen State. The Title SCreen can have a call to LoadContent() which will reload all assets (effectively restarting the game completely).

Not sure if that helps. =X

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help! :)